# Android currentTimeMillis strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, date, time, timestamp

Im gonna try to summarise as much as possible. I need to use the currentTimeMillis to introduce it in differents rows of a database. I know nanoTime is more efficient but I want to have the timestamps in millies passed since 1970 format, so I prefer to use this one.

The behaviour I got is really strange. I log currentTimeMillis and it prints different values. However, if I pass that SAME value to the db, it always the same in every row! Code would make it more complicated, but this piece of code can be useful:

```
long currentTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d("Time", String.valueOf(currentTimeMs));
bufferSignals.get(0).hashData.get(SensorType.TIME_STAMP).data=currentTimeMs;
```

The value I find in the DB is not the same than the log shows me. If instead of writing ...data = currentTimeMs I do ...data = i; being i an iteraror(1,2,3...), it writes different values in every row!

I hope I explained myself clear enough. Any idea whats happening? Anybody run into the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a loop?

Comment: Can you show how u get the data from the database. And yes, you should use nanoTime instead ;)

Comment: actually is not in a loop, its in the function onSensorChanged of Android!

Comment: I forgot to say why Im doing this. The timeStamp of Android for its sensors sometimes uses the 1970 format and sometimes what is called "uptime" (depending on the manufacturer of the device). Thats why I need to this to have always the same format...

Comment: If another thread is updating a database, then the data variable might need to be volatile for that thread to see any updates.

Comment: Yes, another thread is updating the database...I changed the variable to volatile but still the same problem :( great idea though MIchael Krussel!

Comment: Ok, ive made some progress. My data variable is a float, and it seems when I insert currentTimeMs, which is a long, the conversion is done wrong. However, a little earlier in the code I do:

    myData.hashData.put(SensorType.TIME_STAMP, new Data(event.timestamp));

event.timestamp is a long so it get converted to float...but this time the conversion is done good!

Comment: And another x-files more. If I do 

bufferSignals.get(0).hashData.put(SensorType.TIME_STAMP, new Data(System.currentTimeMillis()))

The conversion is done WRONG too.

Comment: Finally I fixed it changing the data variable to a double instead of float.